# NHibernate code completion Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, nhibernate

I know there is a way to enable code completion for hibernate-mapping files.
But I can't remember how I have to do this.
Can someone help me out pls?

Comment: http://blog.benday.com/archive/2006/01/15/3646.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try copying the following files into: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Packages\schemas\xml, or into C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Xml\Schemas.

I'm not sure which is the right place and I put them into both of mine but it works for me.

nhibernate-configuration.xsd
nhibernate-generic.xsd
nhibernate-mapping.xsd

You can get the files from the source of nHibernate